# QGIS using OSM map layer does not accurately display Safegraph polygon geometry data

Tags: qgis, building-heights

Using QGIS, I'm attempting to plot Safegraph Geometry datasets on Open Street Map. What the Safegraph is displaying is purple, whereas the actual polygon, according to the other datasets, is orange. Does anyone know why this is happening?

This is the polygon value I am trying to plot that shows Starbucks in New York City.

```
POLYGON ((-73.98837223649025 40.76919775764554, -73.9882230386138 40.76939606895489, -73.98816905915737 40.76937296228992, -73.98831993341446 40.76917642835297, -73.98837223649025 40.76919775764554))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing! For transparency, I lead product at SafeGraph and just took a look at this record. This is an edge case where the POI is attached to a dated polygon source we'd like to remove. This will be corrected in our November 2022 Places release. Please email me directly (bryan@safegraph.com) if you encounter any more feedback like this.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I will send you an email if I encounter similar problems.